# comparing multiple column values between two files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have two CSV files on a Linux machine, containing data as:

File A

```
Sunil,21,write a line,2312,12-03-2022   
Ashok,22,write a para,2312,12-03-2022
Sam,23,create file using,2312,12-03-2022
```

FileB

```
21,write a line,Writer
21,write a script,Writer
23,create file using,Coder
25,create class,Coder
22,write a para,Poet
22,write a file,Writer
```

Now from FileA column 2 and 3(Eg. 21,write a line) should be compared to FileB and if matched print the 3rd column of FileB:

Output:

```
Writer
Poet
Coder
```

Comment: OK. And what part do you need help with? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want, and assuming your data is as provided then you can achieve this as follows:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{array[$2,$3]; next} ($1,$2) in array { print $NF}' filea fileb
```

Basically what we are doing here is, store column 2 and 3 in `array` stop processing current records (we use `next` ). Then is `$1` and `$2`of fileb in `array` if so print `$NF` where `$NF`  refers the last column of the record.

`NR` and `FNR` are built-in variables in awk. NR refers to the total number of records so far while FNR refers to the number of records in the current file.

Comment: Thanks Valentin!! Appreciate your quick help